# Nginx image filename remove dimensions by modifying uri with regex

Tags: nginx, wordpress, regex

In nginx config, what is the best way to return the original image when the required image size was not found given wordpress image naming/size notation conventions.

So, say if /image-name-150x170.png not found, I want /image-name.png to be returned. -150-170 part can be some other numbers. 
Therefore, I want  dash 1-4 digits x 1-4 digits before dot in the file name to be removed.

I want to put the replace in uri code inside @static_full location block or rewrite. wondering which would be better performance-wise.

```
#some locations here and then 

location ~* ^.+\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg){
       access_log off; 
       log_not_found off; 
       expires max; 
       error_page 404 = @static_full;  #if not found, seek #static_ful
}

location @static_full{
  #modify uri here to remove image dimensions like below
  #uri = remove dash 1-4 digits x 1-4 digits before dot
  #or rewrite to original name 
 }

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
}
```

UPDATE, I figured out how to do it. The following did what I wanted to do.

```
location @static_full{
  #modify uri here to remove image dimensions like below
  #uri = remove dash three digits x three digits before dot
  rewrite "^(.*)(-[\d]{1,4}+x[\d]{1,4}+.)([\w]{3,4})" $1.$3 break;
 }
```

Comment: Why not use a capture group inside your regular expression and a `try_files` in the `location`? Or do you actually want the return code to be a 404?

Comment: I found out how to do it. Please see the update above. It works great.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using `try_files` instead of the `error_page` directive.

```
try_files $uri @static_full;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

EDIT - added full solution:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg) {
    try_files $uri @static_full;

    access_log off; 
    log_not_found off; 
    expires max; 
}

location @static_full {
    rewrite "^(.*)(-[\d]{1,4}+x[\d]{1,4}+.)([\w]{3,4})" $1.$3 break;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
}
```

Comment: Only one try_files can be used. If you use it in one of the location blocks, you can not use it again. I have to use try_files in another location because the site is not just static image files.  
You can check here: 
http://linuxplayer.org/2013/06/nginx-try-files-on-multiple-named-location-or-server
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286850/nginx-try-files-with-multiple-named-locations
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962804/may-i-use-two-named-locations-within-try-files-nginx-directive

Comment: Wrong. You can have as many `try_files` statements as you want. The `error_page` hack is to cascade named location blocks because `try_files` can only have one default action.

Comment: But doesnt work. I only used that solution because try_files ddidnt work, it was common sense to try it and I thought it would work. When it didnt work, I tried searching. It seems using the last try_files directive even if you have multiple ones.

Comment: I don't understand the error you are observing with `try_files`. But I have edited the answer and added the solution I mean, which works for me. *Of course, this has little to do with your question, which you answered yourself ;-)*

Comment: I just tried and your solution works. Thank you. Is there any performance or any drawback of error_page 404 cascading instead of try_files?